# Tapping android screen solves media skipping, how to fix?

Tags: java, android

I wrote an Android app that plays multi-track audio files and it works completely in the simulator.  On the device, it plays for a few seconds and then starts skipping and popping every few seconds.  If I continuously tap the screen in the dead space of the app, the skipping doesn't occur and then recurs about 5 seconds after screen tapping ceases.  I presume that this has something to do with thread priority, but I log the thread priority in the play loop and it never changes.

I'm hoping that somebody can tell me either:

1. a hack where I can simulate a screen tap every second so that I can run a beta test without the app skipping
2. explain a way to debug activity/thread/etc priority when it seems that my thread priority isn't changing when it seems like it is.

Here is how the player code is executed:

```
private class DecodeOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... values) { 
        AudioTrackPlayer.this.decodeLoop();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }
}
```

Here is the relevant player code:

```
private void decodeLoop()
    {

        ByteBuffer[] codecInputBuffers;
        ByteBuffer[] codecOutputBuffers;

        // extractor gets information about the stream
        extractor = new MediaExtractor();
        try {
            extractor.setDataSource(this.mUrlString);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mDelegateHandler.onRadioPlayerError(AudioTrackPlayer.this);
            return;
        }

        MediaFormat format = extractor.getTrackFormat(0);
        String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);

        // the actual decoder
        codec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);
        codec.configure(format, null /* surface */, null /* crypto */, 0 /* flags */);
        codec.start();
        codecInputBuffers = codec.getInputBuffers();

        codecOutputBuffers = codec.getOutputBuffers();

        // get the sample rate to configure AudioTrack
        int sampleRate = format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE);

        Log.i(LOG_TAG,"mime "+mime);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG,"sampleRate "+sampleRate);

        // create our AudioTrack instance
        audioTrack = new AudioTrack(
                AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 
                sampleRate, 
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_5POINT1, 
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 
                AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize (
                        sampleRate, 
                        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_5POINT1, 
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT
                        ), 
                AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM
                );

        // start playing, we will feed you later
        audioTrack.play();
        extractor.selectTrack(0);

        // start decoding
        final long kTimeOutUs = 10000;
        MediaCodec.BufferInfo info = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
        boolean sawInputEOS = false;
        boolean sawOutputEOS = false;
        int noOutputCounter = 0;
        int noOutputCounterLimit = 50;


        while (!sawOutputEOS && noOutputCounter < noOutputCounterLimit && !doStop) {
            //Log.i(LOG_TAG, "loop ");
            noOutputCounter++;
            if (!sawInputEOS) {

                inputBufIndex = codec.dequeueInputBuffer(kTimeOutUs);
                bufIndexCheck++;
               // Log.d(LOG_TAG, " bufIndexCheck " + bufIndexCheck);
                if (inputBufIndex >= 0) {
                    ByteBuffer dstBuf = codecInputBuffers[inputBufIndex];

                    int sampleSize =
                        extractor.readSampleData(dstBuf, 0 /* offset */);
                    //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "SampleLength = " + String.valueOf(sampleSize));
                    long presentationTimeUs = 0;

                    if (sampleSize < 0) {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "saw input EOS.");
                        sawInputEOS = true;
                        sampleSize = 0;
                    } else {
                        presentationTimeUs = extractor.getSampleTime();
                    }
                    // can throw illegal state exception (???)

                        codec.queueInputBuffer(
                                inputBufIndex,
                                0 /* offset */,
                                sampleSize,
                                presentationTimeUs,
                                sawInputEOS ? MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM : 0);



                    if (!sawInputEOS) {
                        extractor.advance();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "inputBufIndex " +inputBufIndex);
                }
            }

            int res = codec.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, kTimeOutUs);

            if (res >= 0) {
                //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "got frame, size " + info.size + "/" + info.presentationTimeUs);
                if (info.size > 0) {
                    noOutputCounter = 0;
                }

                int outputBufIndex = res;
                ByteBuffer buf = codecOutputBuffers[outputBufIndex];

                final byte[] chunk = new byte[info.size];
                buf.get(chunk);
                buf.clear();

                    audioTrack.write(chunk,0,chunk.length);
                    if(this.mState != State.Playing)
                    {
                        mDelegateHandler.onRadioPlayerPlaybackStarted(AudioTrackPlayer.this);
                    }
                    this.mState = State.Playing;
                }
                codec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufIndex, false /* render */);
                if ((info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "saw output EOS.");
                    sawOutputEOS = true;
                }
            } else if (res == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
                codecOutputBuffers = codec.getOutputBuffers();

                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "output buffers have changed.");
            } else if (res == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
                MediaFormat oformat = codec.getOutputFormat();

                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "output format has changed to " + oformat);
            } else {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "dequeueOutputBuffer returned " + res);
            }
        }

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "stopping...");

        relaxResources(true);

        this.mState = State.Stopped;
        doStop = true;

        // attempt reconnect
        if(sawOutputEOS)
        {
            try {
                AudioTrackPlayer.this.play();
                return;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }  

        if(noOutputCounter >= noOutputCounterLimit)
        {
            mDelegateHandler.onRadioPlayerError(AudioTrackPlayer.this);
        }
        else
        {
            mDelegateHandler.onRadioPlayerStopped(AudioTrackPlayer.this);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you monitored the CPU frequency while your application is running? The CPU governor is probably scaling the CPU up on touch and scaling back down on a timer. Increasing the priority on your background thread to [THREAD_PRIORITY_DEFAULT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#THREAD_PRIORITY_DEFAULT%20THREAD_PRIORITY_DEFAULT) will probably fix the issue, the default priority for `AsyncTask` is quite low and not appropriate for Audio.

You could also increase the size of the AudioTrack's buffer to some multiple of the value returned by `getMinBufferSize`, that method only returns the minimum possible buffer for the Class to operate, it does not guarantee smooth playback.

Comment: Increasing the thread priority alone didn't solve the problem but I increased the buffer size by 4x and the popping appears to have vanished.  Thanks for the help!